# Laravel 4 - Mapping/aliassing a column name from L4 Model

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

For my website I'm using Laravel 4 with Eloquent. In my table 'users' there is a column 'active' - tinyint(1) (MYSQL). My Laravel application is serving the content of my users table (without password) to my front-end application in a JSON-format.

In my front-end application I'm using a third party plugin that accepts my JSON as a datasource. 
But that plugin requires the column to be named: isActie (with camelCase).

So my question is: Can I change the label for that column in my JSON-result within Laravel?

Now I'm using: $users = User:All();

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a custom select clause:

```
User::select('id', 'name', 'active as isActive')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that I could use that kind of aliassing in the select.